# Diameter of finite set of points is equal to diameter of its convex hull

Tags: geometry

Let $M\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a finite set of points, $\operatorname{C}(M)$ the convex hull of M and 
$$\operatorname{diam}(M) = \sup_{x,y\in M}\|x-y\|_2$$
be the diameter of $M$

What I want to show now is, that it holds
$$\operatorname{diam}(M) = \operatorname{diam}(\operatorname{C}(M))$$

Because $$M\subseteq\operatorname{C}(M)$$ we obtain $$\operatorname{diam}(M) \le\operatorname{diam}(\operatorname{C}(M))$$ but how to proof that $$\operatorname{diam}(M) \ge \operatorname{diam}(\operatorname{C}(M))$$

I suppose it should be possible to construct a contradiction assuming $\operatorname{diam}(M) <\operatorname{diam}(\operatorname{C}(M))$ but i do not see how at this moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Prove this for a triangle and then use the fact that for every point of $C(M)$ there is a triangle that contains it, there are many ways to go from there.

I hope this helps ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Another method:

- $C(M)$ is compact, so there exist $x_1,x_2 \in C(M)$ such that $d(x_1,x_2)=\mathrm{diam}(C(M))$.
- Let $f : x \mapsto d(x_1,x)$. Because $f$ is convex, $f((1-t)x+ty) \leq \max(f(x),f(y))$.
- Deduce that $x_2 \in \partial M$ and then that $x_2 \in M$.
- With a symmetric argument, you have $x_1 \in M$.

Therefore, $\mathrm{diam}(C(M)) =d(x_1,x_2)\leq \mathrm{diam}(M)$.